# How to create a physics material with specific friction for the character to fall over faster?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, game-development

I am making a 2.5d platformer with a pill as a character, which has a very specific movement. Instead of freezing its z rotation so it won't fall over, the pill tumbles over on and on.
[image]

So, the problem is that when I put a maxfriction physics material on the pill, it tumbles over great but the gravity when you let go of the move key is extremely slow which is pretty annoying.

However, when I assign a nofriction material on it, it doesn't rotate at all.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem, I know it is very specific, but I am a beginner in unity and I have no idea how to fix this.
Thank you! Emiel

Comment: That’s why there is drag and friction. Friction is like concrete vs ice. One you can’t skid on easy the other easy as. Then there is drag. Which is the difference between a bullet and parachute. One cuts through air the other slows you down